# Is there a scala replacement for Guava MultiSet and Table concepts?

Tags: scala, guava, scala-collections

To use guava `Table` and `Multiset` in scala? are there already different concenpts in scala instead of importing guava library for this usage?

Comment: I guess you could use `Map[(R, C), V]` instead of `Table<R, C, V>` and `Map[T, Int]` instead of `Multiset<T>`.

Comment: i don't see i can do `Map[T, Int].add("mykey")` and then `Map[T, Int].size("mykey")` and it would return how many items I added of type  `T`

Comment: code sample for `add` is too big for comment. Added as answer.

Comment: Note that if you want to count elements in collection you don't need to use `Multiset` in scala - you could just use `groupBy` like this: `val counts = elements.groupBy(identity).map{ case (k, v) => k -> v.size } withDefaultValue 0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Map[(R, C), V]` instead of `Table<R, C, V>` and `Map[T, Int]` instead of `Multiset<T>`. You could also add helper methods to `Map[T, Int]` like this:

```
implicit class Multiset[T](val m: Map[T, Int]) extends AnyVal {
  def setAdd(e: T, i: Int = 1) = {
    val cnt = m.getOrElse(e, 0) + i
    if (cnt <= 0) m - e
    else m.updated(e, cnt)
  }
  def setRemove(e: T, i: Int = 1) = setAdd(e, -i)
  def count(e: T) = m.getOrElse(e, 0)
}

val m = Map('a -> 5)

m setAdd 'a
// Map('a -> 6)

m setAdd 'b
// Map('a -> 5, 'b -> 1)

m setAdd ('b, 10)
// Map('a -> 5, 'b -> 10)

m setRemove 'a
// Map('a -> 4)

m setRemove ('a, 6)
// Map()

m count 'b
// 0

(m setAdd 'a) count 'a
// 6
```

Comment: and if we want to be concurrent then to `def setAdd(e: T, i: Int = 1) = {    val cnt = m.getOrElse(e, 0) + i` we are going to add concurrency if we want to be concurrent... doesnt that means we are re-implementing guava ConcurrentMultiset?

Comment: @Jas: sharing mutable collection in different thread - I don't think it's a scala way.

Comment: @Jas: note that this implementation is immutable.

Comment: How would you query a Map[(R, C), V] for all mappings corresponding to a given R (or C)? I mean, without filtering the whole map...

Answer (score 1):

This is a first naive implementation using `Map[(R, C), V]` as a delegated collection.
`rows`and `columns` are used as indexes for the `m: Map`.

```
package utils.collections

import utils.collections.Table.Cell

class Table[R, C, V](val m: Map[(R, C), V], val rows: Map[R, List[(R, C)]], val columns: Map[C, List[(R, C)]]) {

  def containsValue(value: V): Boolean = m.values.exists(_.equals(value))

  def values(): List[V] = m.values.toList

  def get(rowKey: R, columnKey: C): Option[V] = m.get(rowKey, columnKey)

  def apply(rowKey: R, columnKey: C): V = m.apply((rowKey, columnKey))

  def cellSet(): Set[Cell[R, C, V]] = m.map { case ((r, c), v) => Cell(r, c, v) }.toSet

  def contains(rowKey: R, columnKey: C): Boolean = m.contains((rowKey, columnKey))

  def put(rowKey: R, columnKey: C, value: V): Table[R, C, V] = {
    val keys: (R, C) = (rowKey, columnKey)
    new Table(
      m = m + ((keys, value)),
      rows = rows + ((rowKey, keys::rows.getOrElse(rowKey, List.empty))),
      columns = columns + ((columnKey, keys::columns.getOrElse(columnKey, List.empty)))
    )
  }

  def putAll(table: Table[_ <: R, _ <: C, _ <: V]): Table[R, C, V] = Table(m.++(xs = table.m))

  def remove(rowKey: R, columnKey: C): Table[R, C, V] = {
    val keys: (R, C) = (rowKey, columnKey)
    val updatedRows: Map[R, List[(R, C)]] = rows.get(rowKey) match {
      case Some(keysWithRow) if keysWithRow.diff(List(keys)).nonEmpty => rows + ((rowKey, keysWithRow.diff(List(keys))))
      case _ => rows - rowKey
    }
    val updatedColumns: Map[C, List[(R, C)]] = columns.get(columnKey) match {
      case Some(keysWithColumn) if keysWithColumn.diff(List(keys)).nonEmpty => columns + ((columnKey, keysWithColumn.diff(List(keys))))
      case _ => columns - columnKey
    }
    new Table(
      m = m - keys,
      rows = updatedRows,
      columns = updatedColumns
    )
  }

  def row(rowKey: R): Map[C, V] = m.filterKeys(k => rows.get(rowKey).exists(_.equals(k))).map { case ((_, c), v) => (c, v) }

  def containsRow(rowKey: R): Boolean = rows.exists(_.equals(rowKey))

  def rowMap(): Map[R, Map[C, V]] = m.groupBy { case ((r, _), _) => r }.map { case (r, subMap) => (r, subMap.map { case ((_, c), v) => (c, v) }) }

  def rowKeySet(): Set[R] = rows.keySet

  def column(columnKey: C): Map[R, V] = m.filterKeys(k => columns.get(columnKey).exists(_.equals(k))).map { case ((r, _), v) => (r, v) }

  def containsColumn(columnKey: C): Boolean = columns.exists(_.equals(columnKey))

  def columnMap(): Map[C, Map[R, V]] = m.groupBy { case ((_, c), _) => c }.map { case (c, subMap) => (c, subMap.map { case ((r, _), v) => (r, v) }) }

  def columnKeySet(): Set[C] = columns.keySet

  def size(): Int = m.size

  def isEmpty: Boolean = m.isEmpty

}

object Table {

  case class Cell[R, C, V](rowKey: R, columnKey: C, value: V)

  def empty[R, C, V] = new Table[R, C, V](Map.empty, Map.empty, Map.empty)

  def apply[R, C, V](m: Map[(R, C), V]): Table[R, C, V] = {
    val rows: Map[R, List[(R, C)]] = m.keys.groupBy { case (r, c) => r }.map { case (r, keys) => r -> keys.toList }
    val columns: Map[C, List[(R, C)]] = m.keys.groupBy { case (r, c) => c }.map { case (c, keys) => c -> keys.toList }
    new Table[R, C, V](m, rows, columns)
  }

}
```

Comment: Hello. Please don't dump code as an answer, explain your train of thought so users can understand what's going on. Cheers!

Comment: It's the implementation of guava Table interface using `Map[(R, C), V]` as a delegated collection.