# Scala vector splicing (maintaining sorted sequence)

Tags: scala, sorting, collections

I need to maintain a sorted sequence (mutable or immutable — I don't care), dynamically inserting elements into the middle of it (to keep it sorted) and removing them likewise (so, random access by index is crucial).

The best thing I came onto is using a Vector and scala.collections.Searching from 2.11, and then:

```
var vector: Vector[Ordered]
... 
val ip = vector.search(element)
```

Inserting:

```
vector = (vector.take(ip.insertionPoint) :+ element) ++ vector.drop(ip.insertionPoint)
```

Deleting:

```
vector.patch(from = ip.insertionPoint, patch = Nil, replaced = 1)
```

Doesn't look elegant to me, and I suspect performance issues. Is there a better way? Splicing sequences seems like a very basic operation to me, but I can't find an elegant solution.

Comment: "dynamically inserting elements into the middle of it (to keep it sorted) " but to know where to put it, you have to traverse the list up to that point anyway. That makes a list not that bad for this operation (or you can binary chop, or something, but anyway, it's not an O(1) operation).  When you delete, are you deleting by index, or by value, or something else?

Comment: Also, `vector.take` .. `vector.drop` is `.splitAt`. But you probably wanted `.span (_<= element)`

Comment: @Paul Binary search is O(log N), which is fine too. No traversal is needed. scala.collection.Searching uses binary search. Deletion is by index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`SortedSet`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/sets.html). Default implementation of `SortedSet` is [immutable `red-black tree`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet). There is also a [mutable implementation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.TreeSet).

```
SortedSet[Int]() + 5 + 3 + 4 + 7 + 1
// SortedSet[Int] = TreeSet(1, 3, 4, 5, 7)
```

`Set` contains no duplicate elements. In case you want to count duplicate elements you could use `SortedMap[Key, Int]` with elements as keys and counts as values. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21114643/406435) for `MultiSet` emulation using `Map`.

Comment: I would, but I need to be able to add multiple equal items and don't lose them while iterating through the sequence. Can I do that with SortedSet?